# Create a link to open a specific tab on an accordion

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I have an accordion in tailwind.

How can I open the next element after filling the form in my first element

```
<div id="accordion-collapse" data-accordion="collapse">
      <h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-1">
        <button type="button"
          class="flex items-center focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 justify-between p-5 w-full font-medium text-left border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0 text-gray-900 dark:text-white bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 rounded-t-xl"
          data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-1" aria-expanded="true"
          aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-1">
          <span>STEP 1</span>
          <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0 rotate-180" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="accordion-collapse-body-1" aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-1">
        <div class="p-5 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 border-b-0">
          <form>
            <div class="grid gap-6 mb-6 md:grid-cols-2">
              <div>
                <input type="text" id="first_name"
                  class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                  placeholder="NAME" required>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="text" id="last_name"
                  class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                  placeholder="LAST NAME" required>
              </div>      
            </div>              
            <a href="#accordion-collapse-body-2">NEXT</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-2">
        <button type="button"
          class="flex items-center focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 justify-between p-5 w-full font-medium border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0 text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800"
          data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-2" aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-2">
          <span>STEP 2</span>
          <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="accordion-collapse-body-2" class="hidden" aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-2">
        <div class="p-5 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0">
          <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.3.3/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
  </div>
```

I tried with the a href tag setting the ID of the following element but it doesn't work.
How can I do that after I fill in the first and last name, with the next button go to the next accordion

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-2"` to the *Next* link to open the second accordion panel:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.8.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="accordion-collapse" data-accordion="collapse">
  <h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-1">
    <button type="button" class="flex items-center focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 justify-between p-5 w-full font-medium text-left border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0 text-gray-900 dark:text-white bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800 rounded-t-xl"
      data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-1">
      <span>STEP 1</span>
      <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0 rotate-180" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="accordion-collapse-body-1" aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-1">
    <div class="p-5 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 border-b-0">
      <form>
        <div class="grid gap-6 mb-6 md:grid-cols-2">
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="first_name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="NAME" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="LAST NAME" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#accordion-collapse-body-2" data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-2">NEXT</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="accordion-collapse-heading-2">
    <button type="button" class="flex items-center focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 justify-between p-5 w-full font-medium border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0 text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800"
      data-accordion-target="#accordion-collapse-body-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-collapse-body-2">
      <span>STEP 2</span>
      <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="accordion-collapse-body-2" class="hidden" aria-labelledby="accordion-collapse-heading-2">
    <div class="p-5 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 border-b-0">
      <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.3.3/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! and how could I validate that the user fills in his data (name and last name) before going to the next accordion?

Comment: You'd want to look at using JavaScript.